# how to split the string in to array based on required ccondition

Tags: php, string, split, explode

I want to split the string in to array and store the values in table
The string is

```
$string="34=No,46=fgbfb,48=NA,29=NA,45=dsd,49=InConclusive,43=1BHK,35=NA,38=12,39=2,27=q1,41=Others,52=fgfdg,47=fgfg,31=Chawl,33=UpperMiddleClass,37=SelfOwned,30=fdgfdgb,50=fgfdgb,51=fgfdg,32=NA,44=[Refrigerator,Airconditioner]";
```

I tried explode(',',$string);
but i don't want to split the object array ie(44=[Refrigerator,Airconditioner]) this i want like 44 and Refrigerator,Airconditioner

Expected outcome:-

```
 Array ( 
        [0] => 34=No 
        [1] => 46=fgbfb 
        [2] => 48=NA 
        [3] => 29=NA 
        [4] => 45=dsd 
        [5] => 49=InConclusive 
        [6] => 43=1BHK 
        [7] => 35=NA 
        [8] => 38=12 
        [9] => 39=2 
        [10] => 27=q1 
        [11] => 41=Others 
        [12] => 52=fgfdg 
        [13] => 47=fgfg 
        [14] => 31=Chawl 
        [15] => 33=UpperMiddleClass 
        [16] => 37=SelfOwned 
        [17] => 30=fdgfdgb 
        [18] => 50=fgfdgb 
        [19] => 51=fgfdg 
        [20] => 32=NA 
        [21] => 44=[Refrigerator,Airconditioner] 
    )
```

Comment: use another separator. If you don't have control over the separator in the string, you can replace it using preg_replace('/,(\d+=)/', 'XXX$1'. Use your new separator (XXX) instead to explode

Comment: can you give me example.

Comment: no spoon feeding. try it first

Comment: what is the expected outcome?

Comment: Please use two seperator. One for 44 and all other will be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution which work in all possible cases:-

```
<?php
$string="34=No,46=fgbfb,48=NA,29=NA,45=dsd,49=InConclusive,43=1BHK,35=NA,38=12,39=2,27=q1,41=Others,52=fgfdg,47=fgfg,31=Chawl,33=UpperMiddleClass,37=SelfOwned,30=fdgfdgb,50=fgfdgb,51=fgfdg,32=NA,44=[Refrigerator,Airconditioner]";

$string = str_replace(["[","]"], ["{","}"], $string); // convert `[` to `{` and `]` to `}`
$array = preg_split('/(,)(?=(?:[^}]|{[^{]*})*$)/',$string); // split string by `,` and ignore `,` between `{}`
echo "<pre/>";print_r($array);  // print array
foreach ($array as &$ar){ // iterate through array
    $ar = str_replace(["{","}"], ["[","]"], $ar); // convert `{` to `[` and `}` to `]`

}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($array); // print desired array
```

Output:- https://eval.in/725457

Answer (score 2):

Just use a proper regex with `preg_match_all`:

```
/\d+=(?:\[[^]]*]|[^,]*)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3xC9O2/1).

**Details**:

- `\d+`  - 1+ digits
- `=` - a `=`
- `(?:\[[^]]*]|[^,]*)` - either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `\[[^]]*]` - a `[` followed with 0+ chars other than `]` and then a `]`
  - `|`  - or
  - `[^,]*` - 0+ chars other than `,`.

If the arrays can have nested `[...]` inside, you will need to use a bit more complex regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/3xC9O2/2)):

```
/\d+=(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|[^,]*)/
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/gadWrP):

```
$string="34=No,46=fgbfb,48=NA,29=NA,45=dsd,49=InConclusive,43=1BHK,35=NA,38=12,39=2,27=q1,41=Others,52=fgfdg,47=fgfg,31=Chawl,33=UpperMiddleClass,37=SelfOwned,30=fdgfdgb,50=fgfdgb,51=fgfdg,32=NA,44=[Refrigerator,Airconditioner]";
preg_match_all('~\d+=(?:\[[^]]*]|[^,]*)~', $string, $results);
print_r($results[0]);
```

Comment: @Anant: Thank you for commenting, I did not notice the formatting was broken :) Fixed.